# Cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

```
public class OutdoorFragment extends Fragment  {
private GoogleMap googleMap;
double latitude = 1.31039;
double longitude = 103.7784;

public OutdoorFragment() {
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outdoor, container,
            false);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Koh Chi Hao ");

    // adding marker

    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);


    return rootView;
}


private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
         googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
```

}

Hi there, inside my `initializeMap()` , `googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` keeps on saying that `Cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment` . I am not sure what is happening . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It may have to do with the fragment class you have defined on the layout. Could you please show your R.layout.fragment_outdoor file?

Comment: Are you using the `Fragments` from the `support library` and not `android.app.`? Is the Activity a `FragmentActivity` or an `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: Try to use `googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); ` instead

Comment: Use com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in ur xml file or use getSupportFragmentManager() than getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change;

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

with this;

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Note that `getSupportFragmentManager` is from **android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity**.

Good luck.

Comment: I am facing this issue: "Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'". Using SupportMapFragment with v4 Fragment, still giving cast exception in editor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use android.support.v7.app.Fragment;

And need to use getSupportFragmentManager

Basically you need v7 library

Answer (score 1):

Check your activity layout. The fragment with map must have the following attribute `name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` to indicate which fragment class you use.

Comment: isnt it class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" ? or does it means the same?

Comment: Looks like it's the same thing http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html